# Maximum value of abc where abc = a + b + c and a,b,c positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I came across an exercise in an algebra book which is the question in the title of this post.

We can assume WLOG that $a \leq b \leq c$. The book gave a hint: show that $ab \leq 3$.

I was able to figure out the answer using the hint: it implies $(a,b) = (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),$ and then after substitution you get that $(a,b,c) = (1,2,3)$ is the only option with $b \leq c$.

I have no idea how to show $ab \leq 3$ though. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $a\le b\le c$, we have
$$abc=a+b+c\le c+c+c=3c $$